# CircleCI run pylama/pycodestyle not terminating

Tags: circleci, pycodestyle

I'm trying to use CircleCI to check if the codestyle guidlines have been applied correctly otherwise it should fail.

This is the config I have

```
  - run:
      name: Check codestyle guidlines
      command: |
        . venv/bin/activate
        pylama --options setup.cfg --ignore C901
        pycodestyle --config setup.cfg
```

But the task keeps running on forever. I don't know why!?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, had to exclude the `vent/*` directory in the `setup.cfg` since it's in the same directory as the actual application and it contains all libraries